# IIS URL Rewrite Outbound PostBackUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I'm trying to write URLs inside my Web Applications both In- and Outbound using IISs URLRewriter like so:

`www.domain.net/SomeSite.aspx` to `www.domain.net/SomeSite` using this RegEx for Inbound:

`^([A-Za-z0-9]+)([\?A-Za-z0-9=&]+)?$`, much to my surprise, this actually works, also for URLs such as `www.domain.net/SomeSite.aspx?abc=1` => `www.domain.net/SomeSite?abc=1` using this Rewrite Action: `{R:1}.aspx?{R:2}`

But now, for Outbound, I'd like to have the same effect so the user actually sees `www.domain.net/SomeSite` even though my webapplication might be referencing ~/SomeSite.aspx internally.

I use the following RegEx for that:

`^([A-Za-z0-9]+).aspx([\?A-Za-z0-9=&#]+)?$` and rewrite the URL like so: `/{R:1}{R:2}`

In general this works, alas, it does not for e.g. `Response.Redirect` executed in CodeBehind and neither does it work for `PostBackUrl`s from `asp:Button`s.

Does anyone have any idea how to rewrite this outbound rule so it actually catches every link regardless of how I referenced it?

Thanks,

Dennis

Edit:

Some examples since I suppose I wasn't quite as clear as I thought:

User enters `www.domain.com/Login` in Browser, Inbound-Rule catches and redirects to `www.domain.com/Login.aspx` yet shows `/Login` in the Address Bar, this behaviour is fine.

However, when I click on i.e. an asp:Button with PostBackUrl `Login.aspx` the Address Bar will show `Login.aspx` instead of the desired `Login`, how to get exactly this behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you change the PostBackUrl to /Login instead of Login.aspx? I *think* that should work, at least that's how I handle normal anchor tags (saves the Outbound having to do it then!)

Comment: Yep, that'd work, but it'd be amazingly inconvenient since I'd need to do my debugging on IIS instead of the Development Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the only thing I needed to do was add an Inbound Redirect Rule and set `stopProcessing` to true for both rules. Here's the result:

```
<rules>
        <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9]+)([\?A-Za-z0-9#=&amp;]+)?$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx{R:2}" />
        </rule> 
        <rule name="CleanTest" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx([a-zA-Z0-9\?#=&amp;]+)?$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
        </rule>
</rules>
```